# Linear span problems

Tags: linear-algebra

> Determine the dimension of $\operatorname{span}(\underline{a}-\underline{b},\underline{a}+\underline{b}+\underline{c},-2\underline{a}-\underline{c})$, given $\underline{a},\underline{b}$ and $\underline{c}$ are linearly independent.

I know that

$$\begin{align*}\operatorname{span}( \underline{a}-\underline{b},\underline{a}+\underline{b}+\underline{c},-2\underline{a}-\underline{c}) &= \operatorname{span}( 2\underline{a}+\underline{c},\underline{a}+\underline{b}+\underline{c},-2\underline{a}-\underline{c}) \\ &= \operatorname{span}( \underline{0},\underline{a}+\underline{b}+\underline{c},-2\underline{a}-\underline{c}) \\ &=\operatorname{span}( -\underline{a}+\underline{b},-2\underline{a}-\underline{c})\end{align*}$$
But I don't understand why I can conclude that these two are in the basis and therefore the dimension is 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a,b,c$ is the standard basis. So the vectors in coordinates are given by
$$
u=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}, \;v=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}, \; w=\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 0 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We want to determine $n=\dim span(u,v,w)$. Clearly $1\le n\le 3$ by definition here. But because $u+v+w=0$, we have $n\le 2$. However, each two are linearly independent, so $n=2$.